# Table not included as layer with result map service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-10.4

I published a geoprocessing service that outputs (1) a feature layer and (2) a stand alone table. The goal is to join these two on the client side... given the size of the table, it takes too long to join them on the server and use "Copy feature" to create a permanent layer.

According to [this documentation](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/result-map-service.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_9B3FC6B8299D4E23B078D892B2F8B5DC), GPRecordSet data types should be included in the resulting map service (I am assuming a table is this type). However, it is not included after a successful run of the task. Here's subset of the code:

```
result_layer_var = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management( geography, "Result_layer" )

###... Do some spreadsheet work using Pandas ...###

result_spreadsheet_path = os.path.join( scratch_folder, "Result_spreadsheet.csv" )
pandas_table.to_csv( result_spreadsheet_path )
result_table_var = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion( result_spreadsheet_path, scratch_gdb, "Results_table")

arcpy.SetParameter(3, result_layer_var)
arcpy.SetParameter(4, result_table_var)
```

Any thoughts on why the table isn't being included in the resulting map service?

**More infomation:**

***GP settings***

[image]

***Using "Table View" As parameter type***

[image]
[image]

***Using "Table" As parameter type***

[image]
[image]

***Results from both -- notice that E_Output (table) is not included in map service***

[image]
[image]

Why is the GPRecordSet (table) subject to the "exceededTransferLimit: true" but the GPFeatureRecordSetLayer (feature layer) is not... they both have the same number of records.